# Making an "answer space" before the item number in enumitem package

Tags: lists, enumitem

It is customary in our country to put an answer line just before the item number in test papers just like what appears below. I am creating a template that my peers who are just recently converting to LaTeX can use so that they can easily implement this list style. I would like to improve upon this so that I can use the option `align=right` and still maintain answer lines that are flushed to the left. This means automatically decreasing the length of `\answerline` as the space occupied by the item numbers increases. Do you have a better way to do this?

```
\documentclass[preview, border=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\answerline}{\makebox[0.5in]{\hrulefill}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep, label = {{\protect\answerline~\arabic*.}},align=left, leftmargin=*]
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like it the items to be aligned right but the lines flushed to the left.

[image]

Comment: It has been a long time since my last post here. Thanks in advance for the answers, my friends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative might be eating off the line width as the item label width increases which also saves a bit of horizontal space.

```
\documentclass[preview, border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep, 
                  label = {{\protect\makebox[0.5in - \widthof{\arabic*}]{\hrulefill}\arabic*.}},
                  align=left, 
                  leftmargin=*]
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, percusse. So it is that bit of `calc` magic. Thanks!

Comment: @hpesoj626 My pleasure. By the way any kind of width measuring stuff works, `calc` is the first popped in my mind (though I would expect it to be pgfmath :P)